# Variation image click change attribute dropdown selected value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm trying to make it so that by clicking on an attribute's photo, I also update the selection in the attribute's dropdown

In content-single-product.php I added

```
// get the product variations
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    if ( !empty( $product_variations ) ) {
        ?>
    <div class="product-variation-images">
    <?php
    foreach($product_variations as $product_variation) {
        // get the slug of the variation
        $product_attribute_name = $product_variation['attributes'];
        ?>
        <div class="product-variation-image product-variation-<?php echo $product_attribute_name ?>" id="product-variation-<?php echo $product_variation['variation_id']; ?>" data-attribute="<?php echo $product_attribute_name ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $product_variation['image']['src']; ?>" alt="">

        </div><!-- #product-variation-image -->
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Then I added to functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts');
function custom_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (is_product()) {
        global $product;
        $product = wc_get_product();

        wp_enqueue_script('custom-variation-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-variation-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_localize_script('custom-variation-script', 'wc_single_product_params', array(
            'variations' => $product->get_available_variations()
        ));
    }
}
```

then in custom-variation-script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Klik na sliku atributa
    $('.product-variation-image').on('click', function () {
        var attributeValue = $(this).data('attribute');

        // Pronađi odgovarajuću opciju u dropdownu
        var select = $('select[name^="attribute_' + attributeValue + '"]');
        
        if (select.length) {
            // Postavi vrijednost dropdowna
            select.val(attributeValue);

            // Pokreni događaj za ažuriranje WooCommerce varijacija
            select.trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work.. Can someone help me?

I tried several ways but none work's...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Klik na sliku atributa
    $('.product-variation-image').on('click', function () {
        // Pronađi id varijacije iz data atributa
        var variationId = $(this).attr('id').replace('product-variation-', '');

        // Pronađi odgovarajući dropdown za varijaciju
        var select = $('select.variation_id');

        // Postavi vrijednost dropdowna
        if (select.length) {
            select.val(variationId);

            // Pokreni događaj za ažuriranje WooCommerce varijacija
            select.trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

The attributes for variations in the product are "Color" and "Weight":

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, I managed to solve it like this in the end

In content-single-product.php

```
<?php
if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
    // get the product variations
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $color_taxonomy = 'pa_color';
    $weight_taxonomy = 'pa_weight';

    if (!empty($available_variations)) {
        echo '<div class="product-variation-images">';

        foreach ($available_variations as $variation_data) {
            // get the slug of the color variation attribute
            $color_slug = isset($variation_data['attributes']['attribute_' . $color_taxonomy]) ? $variation_data['attributes']['attribute_' . $color_taxonomy] : '';
            $weight_slug = isset($variation_data['attributes']['attribute_' . $weight_taxonomy]) ? $variation_data['attributes']['attribute_' . $weight_taxonomy] : '';

            echo '<div class="product-variation-image product-variation-' . $color_slug . '-' . $weight_slug . '" data-color="' . $color_slug . '" data-weight="' . $weight_slug . '">
                <img src="' . esc_url($variation_data['image']['src']) . '" alt="">
            </div><!-- #product-variation-image -->';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Then i added in my child functions.php

```
function variable_product_jquery_script()
{
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        $color_taxonomy = 'pa_color';
        $weight_taxonomy = 'pa_weight';

        wc_enqueue_js("jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.product-variation-images').on('click', '.product-variation-image', function () {
                const colorAttr = $(this).data('color'),
                      weightAttr = $(this).data('weight'),
                      colorSelect = $('select#' + '{$color_taxonomy}'),
                      weightSelect = $('select#' + '{$weight_taxonomy}');

                if (colorSelect.length && weightSelect.length) {
                    // Clear previous weight selection
                    weightSelect.val('').trigger('change');

                    // Set new color selection
                    colorSelect.val(colorAttr).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        });");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!
@LoicTheAztec Thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** - There are some mistakes in your code. Try the following replacement instead:

In template content-single-product.php file:

```php
if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
    // get the product variations
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $taxonomy             = 'pa_color';
    $color_attribute      = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);

    if ( ! empty($available_variations) && ! empty($color_attribute) ) {
        echo '<div class="product-variation-images">';

        foreach($available_variations as $variation_data) {
            if( ! isset($variation_data['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) continue;

            // get the slug of the variation attribute
            $term_slug = $variation_data['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy];

            echo '<div class="product-variation-image product-variation-'.$term_slug.'" id="product-variation-'.$variation_data['variation_id'].'" data-attribute="'.$term_slug.'">
                <img src="'.$variation_data['image']['src'].'" alt="">
            </div><!-- #product-variation-image -->';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

In your child theme's functions.php file:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'variable_product_jquery_script', 5);
function variable_product_jquery_script() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_color';

        wc_enqueue_js("$(document.body).on('click', '.product-variation-image', function () {
            const attrVal = $(this).data('attribute'),
                  select  = $('table.variations select#{$taxonomy}');
            
            if (select.length) {
                select.val(attrVal).trigger('change');
            }
        });");
    }
}
```

Remove the custom-variation-script.js file.

Tested and works on variable products with 2 attributes set for variations: Only the color attribute generate the variations as the second attribute is set as default (with no selected value).

**Important:**

The code will only work if the variations are generated from the Color attribute.
It will work if the "Weight" attribute has only one value, or if the "Weight" attribute is set in each variation as "Any" *(no selected value)*.

Comment: Hello @loictheaztec thank you for your answer i have tried your solution for some reason it's doent work. I will left you here url for the demo .. Maybe you can figure out what am i doing wrong... 

https://razmena.co.rs/ims/product/nemanja-test/

Comment: As said at the end of my answer, this can only work with a unique attribute for variation. I remember you that you didn't explain in your question that you have also another attribute for weight. It will never work with more than one attributes for variations…

Comment: Clear... Do you have any idea how it could work if the second part of the variation just stands as default? Thank you so so much for your time

Comment: thank you so much! I have tried your code but for some reason now thumbs are not clicable.. Nothing happends.

Comment: can you please check what's wrong thank you so so much!